# Can someone check if my Entity Relationship Diagram is correct?

Tags: sql, oracle, diagram, erd

I am pretty new at database. I just want to see if my logic is correct or mostly correct (I know I am not 100% correct lol) but I want to see where I am wrong. Please take a look and give some feedback! I made this diagram off of this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results/home

[Picture of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj8nR.png)

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg2O9.png)

Thank you so much!

(I updated the original diagram!)

Comment: For statrters, you would tend to model age via D.O.B in normal systems. You could extract event year and have a union with athlete to store age at the time of the event. If you look at the spreadsheet Christina Jocoba.... you will see what I mean. The ID column 1 seems to refer to an Athlete id - rather than a result id...

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I've been working on it for the past 3 hours. Let me know what you think with the updated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model isn't too far away. I would structure the tables slightly differently. From here you can join tables in any way you want to go the data you need.

[image: see model here]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the contribution! I definitely see how this model can be better but I'm just confused about the Competitor entity. Is that supposed be the result or is this something entirely different? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hi @ThatOneGoi Athletes can take part in 0 or more events, events involve 1 or more athletes, so the Competitor table lists all the athetes that take a part in a specific event. the Competitor table will contain the PK of Athlete and Games_Event as Foreign Keys. You could also store result info in here, e.g. position, time, points etc. You may want a separate table for results if events have multiple rounds etc. It can get as complex as you need it to be.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! Helps a lot :) Definitely a lot better than my tables but are my entity's inherently wrong?

Comment: Well not really, you could do it the way you have in the updated version if all you were interested in is listing which athletes won each event, but it would not be very efficient in a real world application/database. Your data fields need some work, e.g. you don't need to store the YEAR in the Results table if it links to the SITE, which contains the YEAR. Suggest you read a little about Data Normalisation to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would model things. Sorry for hastily written scrawl.
Since the weight/height of a person can change over time, I introduced a Athelete/Event association table. The sex - I said could be on that table too if someone underwent gender re-assignment! But you get the gist.
The abbreviation on Country related to the NOC, the full name the team in your spreadsheet. You could derive the medal from the position in the result table if you had it. Things like first equal may mess things up in reality. So there is no silver - just a bronze. But you can equally add medal on results table.

[image: Olympics ERD]

Comment: Oh wow that is definitely a step further and I never would've thought of it. But thank you! Although it did take me a couple minutes to read haha